# Не работает рекурсивный метод в Java

Tags: java, рекурсия

Нужно сделать рекурсивный метод,при вызове которого получалось бы следующее:

```
repeat("hello", 3)  "hellohellohello"
repeat("this is fun", 1)    "this is fun"
repeat("wow", 0)    ""
repeat("hi ho! ", 5)    "hi ho! hi ho! hi ho! hi ho! hi ho! "
```

Вот мой код

```
public class Test{
public static String repeat(String s, int n) {
    String a="";
    if(n < 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    else if(n==0){
        return a;
    }
    else {
    a=a+s;
    n--;
      }
        return repeat(a,n);
}

public static void main(String[]args){
repeat("hello", 3);
}
}
```

По заданию,при вводе отрицательного числа должно выбрасываться исключение,при вводе нуля метод должен возвращать пустую строку.Эти части кода работают.Не работает сама рекурсия,всегда возвращается пустая строка.Пробовал `return repeat(a,n);` перенести в

```
else {
        a=a+s;
        n--;
        return repeat(a,n);
         }
```

Вывод тот же.В чём проблема?Это задание на рекурсию,через цикл нельзя сделать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
else if(n==0){
    return a;
}
```

Когда доходит до дна рекурсии, в этот момент возвращается пустая строка. На самом деле, идея сделать tail recursion хороша, но с ограничением на только два аргумента вряд ли получится.

Поэтому придется более stack-unfriendly: в основном случае (n > 0) нужно сделать что-то вроде `return s + repeat(s, n - 1);`.

Answer (score 3):

как то так:

```
    public class RecursiveHelp {
        static String recursiveRepeat(String s, int n) {
            if (n == 0) {
                return "";
            } else if (n < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("n должно быть больше 0");
            }
            return s + recursiveRepeat(s, --n);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(recursiveRepeat("hello", 3));
            System.out.println(recursiveRepeat("this is fun", 1));
            System.out.println(recursiveRepeat("wow", 0));
            System.out.println(recursiveRepeat("hi ho! ", 5));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас `a` либо пуста, когда `n == 0`, либо равно `s`.

```
public class Test{
    public static String repeat(String a, String sum, int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        return n == 0 ? sum : repeat(a, sum + a, --n);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println(repeat("hello", "", 3));
    }
}
```

Comment: по условию нужно,что бы метод принимал только 1 строку и 1 число,по типу repeat(String a, int n),но всё равно спасибо за ваше решение